# Finding an upper bound on composite $C^{1}$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, normed-spaces, upper-lower-bounds

The conditions for the problem I am currently tackling is as follows:

> Let $T, M > 0$. Define :
>
> $X_{T} := \{ u \in C^{1} ([0,T]) : ||u||_{T} \leq 2M \}$
>
> where $||u||_{T} \ = \ ^{\text{sup}}_{t \in (0,T)} [|u(t)| +|u'(t)|]$ is the norm of $C^{1} ([0,T])$
>
> Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ belongs to $C^{1} (\mathbb{R})$ and that $f(0) = 0$.
>
> For $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u \in C^{1} ([0,T])$ define:
>
> $\psi(u)(t) \ = \ a + \int^{t}_{0} f(u(s)) \text{d}s$

Small note, not sure if this is relevant, but I have previously shown that $X_{T}$ as defined above is a complete metric space under the above norm.

The question for this problem is as follows:

> Find $M,T > 0$ (or a suitable condition on $M,T > 0$) such that $\psi$ defines a map from $X_{T}$ to itself.

I have found a minimum value $M$ must take in terms of $a, T,$ and $u$ for a given $u \in X_{T}$ but I can't extend this to a general value that works for all $u$.

I would like to be able to find an upper bound for $^{\text{sup}}_{t \in (0,T)} |f(u(t))|$ over all $u \in X_{T}$ but does such a bound exist? I know there is such a bound for each $u$ individually, but I don't think our conditions on $f$ are strict enough that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$. We would need $f$ to be bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ for this to work right?

Can anyone confirm that my hunch is correct, and if so suggest a different approach I might take? Thank you.

Comment: Ah, I feel foolish now. The key is probably the fact that the norm of $u$ is always less than or equal to $2M$. I'm working on it now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my professor made a mistake in setting this question. It does not necessarily have a solution unless we are given a bound $|f| \leq 1$ on some $(−2M,2M)$